# Type incompatibly between dates

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare today's date with dates in a planning to highlight the current task.

```
Sub tasks()
    Dim task As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim debut As Date, fin As Date, today As Date
    today = (Date)
    With Worksheets("Gantt")
        For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            debut = (.Cells(i, 2).Value)
            fin = (.Cells(i, 3).Value)
            Set task = Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 5))
            If (debut <= today) & (today <= fin) Then
            'task.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
                Debug.Print "today = " & today
                Debug.Print "debut = " & debut
                Debug.Print "fin = " & fin
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

My code gives me an `incompatibility type` error in my `if` statement. I have tried to cast all my dates to double type with `CBdl` but it gives me the same error regardless.
The dates in the sheet are "long dates" and I wrote them as `20/02/2020` for example.

Does anyone know what I am missing? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `&` instead of `And` which is trying to concatenate the two dates rather than logically compare the two operations.

Replace with

```
If (debut <= today) And (today <= fin) Then
```

Comment: @JackA Not a stupid mistake, I regularly code in C#, PHP and JavaScript so I'm always using things like `&&` and sticking `;` at the end of lines in my VBA haha

Answer (score 0):

Found two bugs on below two lines.

`For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

`If (debut <= today) & (today <= fin) Then`

Below is the corrected code:

```
Sub tasks()

    Dim task As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim debut As Date, fin As Date, today As Date
    today = (Date)
    With Worksheets("Gantt")
        For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            debut = (.Cells(i, 2).Value)
            fin = (.Cells(i, 3).Value)
            Set task = Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 5))
            If (debut <= today) And (today <= fin) Then
            'task.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
                Debug.Print "today = " & today
                Debug.Print "debut = " & debut
                Debug.Print "fin = " & fin
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand why you changed  `Cells(Rows.Count, 1) ` by  `Cells(Rows.Count, 2)`